# Office Add-In: Calling a REST api not possible despite specifying in AppDomain

Tags: node.js, axios, office365, office-js, office-addins

I'm currently getting started with developing an Office Add-In for Word. That Add-In has to communicate with an REST api. I used the official yeoman generator to generate the project.

Now I want to do request against an rest api hosted on domain "api.example.com".

The official documentation states that i have to add an `<AppDomain>` tag. So my manifest contains the following:

The endpoint uses https, so I added following to the manifest.xml:

```
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>1c664689-bba0-4b55-a99b-09e8d03f263c</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="HelloOffice"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://api.example.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

...

</OfficeApp>
```

Now I want to make a GET call to api in the in the default generated method `run` (gets called when I click on the corresponding link in the taskpane):

```
export async function run() {
  return Word.run(async (context) => {
    /**
     * Insert your Word code here
     */

    // insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
    context.document.body.insertParagraph("Run: Start", Word.InsertLocation.end);
    console.log("Hello Debugger");

    axios.get('https://api.example.com/login')
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        context.document.body.insertParagraph(response.AuthSessionId, Word.InsertLocation.end);
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(function () {
        // always executed
      });

    context.document.body.insertParagraph("Run: End", Word.InsertLocation.end);
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

The call fails with follwing error:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

I also tried make a request to non existing endpoint at the default dev url (`https://localhost:3000/`), which matches `<SourceLocation>` tag. In this case I get:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

Since the error code for the external api (`https://api.example.com`) is `ERR_NETWORK` / `Network Error` and not a HTTP-Error-Code I think its blocking the request to the external domain completly.

Do I miss something?

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Will 'https://api.example.com/login' open in a plain browser window? 2. Are you working on desktop Word or Word on the web? 3. Login is usually done with a call to `displayDialogAsync`, not directly in a taskpane window. Some login providers will not allow their login page to open in an iFrame.

Comment: 1: No, it's an REST endpoint. But in Postman all works fine 2: I tested it on dekstop word and by open `https://localhost:3000/` directly in the browser, both failed. 3: There are more requests than login, this was just an example. All requests are REST, no HTML/Websites